# AngularJs ng-repeat doesn't work if the key starts with "$"

Tags: angularjs

If my key starts with "$", then ng-repeat doesn't work fine. I think angularjs may treat this as a special instruction as $index. Is there a way to make it work?

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <h1 ng-repeat='(key,val) in {"SimpleKey":"This works fine"}'>{{key}}:{{val}}</h1>
  <h1 ng-repeat='(key,val) in {"Key/$/FOO":"This works fine"}'>{{key}}:{{val}}</h1>
  <h1 ng-repeat='(key,val) in {"$/FOO":"This does NOT work fine!"}'>{{key}}:{{val}}</h1>
</div>
```

You can try this at: [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxyrBM)

Comment: why do you need to use the dollar sign?

Comment: There is tons of angular attributes starts with $ or $$ in angular objects, so, if they don't filter out those, you will get extra items in every loop.

Comment: This is angular code, `if (collection.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.charAt(0) != '$') { collectionKeys.push(key); }`, which means you have to fix it in your side.

Comment: Thank you. IMO, this seems to be a limitation or a bug in AngularJs side. Each time to use ng-repeat to iterate over object keys, user needs to ensure each key not start with $, or it won't work and there is no error messages.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have a $ in your key?

Comment: The branch name of source codes in Microsoft TFS starts with "$"

Answer (score 0):

just put space before $ it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space before the key then:

```
<h1 ng-repeat='(key,val) in {" $/FOO":"This work fine!"}'>{{key}}:{{val}}</h1>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYVQLj